# Where firefox browser store user history file

Tags: c#

I want to know where firefox browser store user history. I want to make a small program in c# which delete history of firefox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[***].default\places.sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [Firefox Help for Profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles)?

In Windows 7 & Vista:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

where `%APPDATA%` is shortcut for `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: Hi Christian P, Thanks for your quick reply. Could you please let me know what is actual name of file which store history information. Recently I got a file which name is places.sqlite but it also contain bookmark history. I need to delete only history.

Comment: Thanks. That's why we're all here for ;)

Comment: @user1006996 the history is saved in places.sqlite for FF 3. Look at this similar question, it has a lot of info about what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036/programmatically-access-browser-history

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it's:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\
```

Comment: Could you please let me know name of the file which contains user history file.