# How to open browser history in selenium for firefox?

Tags: selenium

I tried to get browser history with following code:

```
webDriver.get("https://google.com/");
webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "H");
```

But it's not working for me. History is not opened.
Could you please help? How I can check the history browser ?

Comment: Selenium is pretty much limited to the DOM, so browser shortcuts won't work.  In Chrome I think you could set the URL to "chrome://history/".  (You'd then be dealing with Shadow-DOM) Not sure if there's a way in Firefox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically access browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036/programmatically-access-browser-history)

Comment: What is the actual behavior you're looking to accomplish with the history?