# Storing redirect URL for later use

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store the redirect URL for use a few pages later but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it from one place to another.

Usually I'd just pass a variable thru the URL, but since my redirect URL contains URL variables itself, this doesn't exactly work.

To give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do, here's the structure.

**PAGE 1:** User can click a link to add content on **PAGE 2**

**PAGE 2:** User enters text. Submitting the form on this page calls "formsubmit.php" where the MySQL data entries are handled. At the end of *this* I need to redirect the user to **PAGE 1** again. The redirect URL needs to exactly match what was originally on **PAGE 1**

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Have you considered cookies or session?

Comment: You could seriously Rube Goldberg it and call `base64_encode` on the URL and pass it through the querystring (**DO NOT DO THIS! DO NOT DO THIS! THIS IS A JOKE! HA HA HA HA HA!**)  In all seriousness, MoarCodePlz's suggestion, Sessions, are pretty much the correct way to go (way easier than manually doing the cookies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use $_SESSION to store the variable in session memory. As far as specifics go with how to handle this in particular, you should be able to figure it out (store the variable, check if it exists later, if so redirect etc etc) but $_SESSION is going to be much more efficient / less messy than trying to pass things back and forth in query strings.

To declare a session variable you would do something like this:

```
$_SESSION['redirUrl'] = "http://www.lolthisisaurl.com/lolagain";
```

And then to reference it you just do

```
$theUrl = $_SESSION['redirUrl'];
```

Here is some material to get you started: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @MoarCodePlz I added the first code line in **Page 1**. When I call `$_SESSION['redirUrl']` in `formsubmit.php' I get `Undefined variable: _SESSION`

Comment: This means that you're not using PHP sessions yet. There are two ways that you can enable this. 1) Go to your php.ini and set session.auto_start=on. This will make it so that every time a user requests a page from your website that they are given a session and the php handler takes care of all the messiness regarding it. 2) Call session_start() in your PHP file. This will automatically start the session and, again, have the php handler take care of all the messiness.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz But if I echo `$_SESSION['redirUrl']` in **Page 2** it displays just fine. It just wont show up in formsubmit.php

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't show up in formsubmit.php?" How are you intending for it to show up? What do you want to actually happen? Based on what you originally said then you need to, in formsubmit.php, do Header("Location: ".$_SESSION['redirurl']); once all the MySQL stuff has executed.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz Well, not sure if it worked yet bc I'm getting another error before it redirects: `Error adding quote: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: @MoarCodePlz Yeah, I'm fairly sure what you suggested works (though I'm not entirely sure) because I at least *don't* get the `Undefined variable` error. I'll accept your answer for now.

Comment: A caution about using session storage for redirect urls: if a user has multiple tabs open while using the site it is possible for activity in one tab to overwrite the redirect url from activity in another tab.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend either using session variables, or storing the redirect url in a hidden form parameter. Session variables are pretty simple; just initialize the session (once, at the top of each page), and then assign variables to the `$_SESSION` global var:

```
<?php

session_start();
...
$_SESSION['redirect_url'] = whatever.com;
...
```

Hidden form parameters work by sending the data from page to page as form data. On the backend, you would add code that would put the URL to be stored in a form variable:

```
<input type='hidden' name='redirect_url' value='<?php echo $redirect_url; ?>';
```

On each page, you can take the URL out of the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable (whichever is appropriate) and insert it into a hidden form in the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to pass a string that contains elements that would otherwise break a url in a url query.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible solutions :

- get the previous page from `document.referrer` ([edit] find more info on this SO thread : [getting last page URL from history object - cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776942/getting-last-page-url-from-history-object-cross-browser))
- store the previous url via a session variable ([edit] MoarCodePlz pointed this out in his answer)

Regards,

Max

Comment: Will document.referrer be over-written upon submitting the PHP form to itself?

Comment: i think that when you're on PAGE 2, your document.referrer would point to PAGE 1, then when you submit, you can find the PAGE 1 URL (and yes, when you submit, you'll have then PAGE 2 in your referrer)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this hidden field in to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">
```

Then use `header()` to redirect to this page:

```
header('Location: '. $_POST['referer']);
```