# Catch back() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, try-catch, back, http-request

I'm creating a homepage. The content of the page is only get by HTTP-Request. So that the Client never change the page-url. How can I catch the back() function from the Browser to go one step back in my HTTP-Request. The automaticly creating of History of all loaded HTTP-Request is done, maybe I must catch this back() function.

Thanks for Help

Comment: What is your HTTP-Request...? You can make use of the hash part of an URL to create history entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: [Browser Back Button Detection](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/)

Comment: I'm going to create a Script which used this Script...

Thanks for this helpfull link ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to update the hash (`www.mysite.com/#hash`) and then use a mechanism to detect hash change.

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea.. 

Very easy to handle without programming a lot ;)

Comment: @PageCreator -- but yet you dont seem to be using it :-P

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you cannot interfere with the back button etc. as it affects the browsers UX.

The best way would probably be to catch the browsers 'onunload' event which is triggered when the page is left. You could write a custom handler function on the assumption that they are clicking back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the page the user come from, you can use the `document.referrer` (more info on [getting last page URL from history object - cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776942/getting-last-page-url-from-history-object-cross-browser)).

Then you could use this to create a link if needed.

Regards,

Max