# Fill HTML form field with previous URL

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a HTML form that is set up to allow users to report pages on my website to a moderator. In the form, there is a field that requests the URL for the page to be reported.

Each page has a link at the bottom that leads to the report form, and was hoping that I could pre-fill the field with the URL of the page that the user was on before they clicked the link to access the form.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting last page URL from history object - cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776942/getting-last-page-url-from-history-object-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be looking for something like that:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ?>" />
```

while this is the correct answer to the question asked, @quasivivo also posted a more reliable solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] but you can modify this so it cant really be trusted.

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could change your link to pass the REQUEST_URI in the GET stream:

```
 <a href="report.php?url=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>">Report this URL</a>
```

Then add that "url" value to your form page (which I called report.php):

```
 <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo htmlentities(urldecode($_GET['url'])); ?>" />
```

Comment: This is better than using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. The latter can be disabled or faked.

Answer (score 0):

You can put extra info to your link, or just get referer url by php.
Here's example for the 2nd option which is more easier.

```
<?php 
    echo '<input type="text" disabled value="' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] . '" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    last_page = document.referrer;
});
```

Edit: Indeed... I see now this is a duplicate: [getting last page URL from history object - cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776942/getting-last-page-url-from-history-object-cross-browser)