# Get last history item URL using JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, web, history

I would like to retrieve my last history item URL using javascript on Chrome.

I know the document.referrer property, but this property returns the last page that redirect to the current browser path and not the last history item URL.

Is there any way to get the last history item URL? (The result should be the history.previous site URL without the redirect to the previous page).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you  cant get to history in any browser.It would be a serious security violation.If this property was enabled that would mean that anyone can snoop around the history of their users.

But there are some ways(history stealing) #NOT RECOMMENDED
http://www.dicabrio.com/javascript/steal-history.php
http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070228/steal-browser-history-without-javascript/

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776942/getting-last-page-url-from-history-object-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed to get history urls for security reasons.