# Get all browser history asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you access browser history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history)

I want to get all web sites that client visit using his browser ( his history ) so I can get some info from these sites and display it in my site ? 
how can I access his history or his bookmark ?

> i just want to read it only i don't now is this legal or not because
>   of web security

if you have a sample example I will be grateful

Comment: What a terrifying idea. I am glad to say, browser bugs aside, that this is not possible.

Comment: that's not possible without hacking the browser or exploiting some hole/bug...

Comment: Wow that's such a privacy intrusion ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the browser history using javascript. That's personal information that you do not have access to.