# Get stored HTML5 History using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the History.js https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ to develop an application using AJAX that can use the HTML5 History API to change the url and title in the browser.

Any ideas on how to GET the information of the previous page? So for example if I was on the following page `domain.com/about` and then went to `domain.com/about/team` I would be able to get the stored information in the API of the previous page.

Can anyone help? I know the plugin can talk to the back and forward buttons and so knows what the previous page was in the History but just don't know how to actually get the information.

So e.g. `var previousUrl = ????`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history

Comment: Can't you store this when the user clicks a link, and keep a stack of visited pages?

Comment: It's not a duplicate! As I'm asking how to access the information stored by this plugin or rather the HTML5 History API.

Comment: @pimvdb that's what the History API does in the HTML5 spec! But how do you get at it? This plugin is supposed to make it easier to communicate with the API but I haven't seen anything to do with accessing the information?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out this page from Mozilla Dev about the [window History object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). It has some details about the new features introduced through HTML 5 on manipulating the history and state. I haven't used the library you are referring to, but it appears it supports the new commands when available, and uses a fallback technique for older browsers.
Here is a snippet from the website you linked to:

```
// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

So, you can see where the comments are they are using custom functions/methods to manipulate history instead of the methods defined in the standard.