# How to capture and record click event on a link to an external URL?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have the following HTML. I want the URL 'http://www.google.com' to be inserted in the database table on click of the link.

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="insert.jsp">Google</a>
```

The `insert.jsp` contains the connectivity code which works fine on the click of the button, but above code is not working.

Comment: Please elaborate this bit more

Comment: Suppose there is a link on webpage..say www.google.com..on the click event of that i want to insert this link in the mysql database on backend,while the webpage is opening on front end.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rel="ext"` on all those links, it gives additional SEO benefit

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="ext">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" rel="ext">
...
```

And use this piece of JavaScript to record them (I'm for simplicitly taking a little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to make it reliably cross browser compatible without the need to write 100 more lines)

```js
$('a[rel=ext]').click(function(e) {
    var $link = $(this);
    var url = '/log?url=' + encodeURIComponent($link.attr('href'));

    if (e.ctrlKey || $link.attr('target') == '_blank') {
        window.open(url);
    } else {
        window.location = url;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Finally have a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) on an URL pattern of `/log` which does the job

```java
@WebServlet("/log")
public class LogServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private LogService logService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url = request.getParameter("url");

        if (url == null || url.trim().isEmpty()) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            logService.log(url);
            response.sendRedirect(url);
        }
    }

}
```

Don't use JSP for this. It makes no sense.

Comment: +1 but if the browser have javascipt turned off then this wont log those clicks. In that case the href attributes would need to point to the LogServlet directly with the "url" parameter encoded directly in the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpServletRequest interface has a method getRequestURL ( ) that return the url of the current page. use this to assign url of current page in some string variable say reqUrl #Example# String reqUrl = request.getRequestURL() #End# and execute insert command as follows
stmt=con.createStatement(); //create a Statement object 
rst=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into table_name VALUES ('" + reqUrl + "'");

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is of the same domain and of the same application then you could easily do this by Mapping a `Filter` that will intercept each request and will add it to DB asynchronously

But if it is of other domain then you need to rewrite such links so that it would pass from one of your Servlet of your app for example `/GateWatServlet?url=google.com` and you can do the job there in Servlet