# Check if user was previously on another webpage?

Tags: php, html

Hi I was wondering how when a user comes to one of my web pages, say "page.html" I would like to check if the last page they visited before they came to "page.html" was "google.com" (or any other website). Is there a way to do this or must I have control of the the other web page that they are coming from in order to monitor this? I assume this can be done in php if it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access browser history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history)

Comment: He wanted to access browser history, I just wanted to know how to monitor how a user comes to my website, different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the HTTP Referer value, which in PHP you get using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Note that this is an entirely arbitrary value volunteered by the client's browser, so it's not guaranteed to be correct or trustable.

Comment: Also worth noting... Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol. So HTTP_REFERER will be empty if user comes from HTTPS site (e.g. Google), to your HTTP (non secure) site.

Comment: So this value is not very dependable. That is somewhat of an issue, because I need it to be. Any ideas on how I could make it more dependable, or use a different function that is?

Comment: @Twisterz If you do not control the originating server where you could make it hand over some token or cookie or something else... No.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHPs `$_SERVER` variable to get the referrer to your page.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [$_SERVER documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) you want `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
 but take note that it's not always going to be set, it depends on the user agent.

Comment: Is there anyway to guarantee it being set, or using a different function that is more dependable?

Comment: this question has an accepted answer that will help understand when it won't be set : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty