# How can I get the next/forward url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

We have function available to get the back/past url using: `document.referrer`, so is there any way or function to get the "forward" url?

I just want to know if the current page has back or forward links. I have searched lot into the history and history-session but they are very limited due to some security issues.

Is there any way to get the next url?

Comment: @MikiShah he's trying to know ahead of time, not just navigate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the history object. There is no way for your script to know which URL the forward button will lead to, or if it is available at all.

Comment: Hey David ... Yes we cannot read the history object but I need the next url because I am implementing the chrome extension so is it good idea to manage the urls into the json with tabId {1:[url1, url2], 2:[url3, url4]} . Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no programmatic way of extracting the forward or reverse history from a browser. This is a security precaution. You can only trigger movement through the history and not view any of the entries.

A similar question...
[How do you access browser history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history)

To confirm W3C states under "5.5.2 The History interface" in the following specification http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#the-history-interface

"The actual entries are not accessible from script."

**Edit** and I would add that this is the only place that the information is available. If you are developing an extension you may be able to track urls yourself by storing the current url in storage otherwise you are out of luck.