# Is there a javascript API to browser history information (limited to current domain)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-history

Is there a programmatic API to tell what are the recently visited pages (30 days) within my site?

I know such information is already stored in the browser history. As far as security, I only care about pages visited within the site (domain) the script is operating of.
My intention is to use the (Url, title) history information to generate a custom recently visited pages list. My site has million of pages.

If there's no such standard API (this [CSS hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history?rq=1) not being one) then:

1. What would be the theoretical security reason not to allow a given domain see the visits to the domain itself?
2. What other approaches may fit my intention?

Comment: did you try google? [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: @jbabey The question has nothing to do with manipulations.

Comment: did you even visit the link? it's the entire history API. if it ain't listed there, it can't be done.

Comment: Yes. I visited it before posting my question. while it does list things you can do. It doesn't list what you can't do. Perhaps there's some object/api that allows that. Anyway, that should not stop me from asking an open-ended question for any alternatives you might think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the history api that will give you that information from your domain. If you want to do it, use the browsers localstorage to store the URLS when the page loads. Other option is to keep track of it on the server and store it in your database.