# Can I get a page visitors full browser history via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-history

I want to make a simple web app that looks at someone's browsing history and recommends new websites based on what they've viewed, but I'm running into a lot of security and non-standardization. Basically, I want to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible?

I've found that chrome has a special property called `chrome.history` which prompts the user for permission, then returns an array with the information, but it doesn't seem to work anymore after some sort of change to webkit. Mozilla also has something called `window.history`, but I'm not sure it works at all.

Can this be done? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a security problem if this would be a possibility. You can use the `$_SERVER['REFERRAL']` in php to see where the user can from before it was on you website, but only for non-httpS websites.

If this would be a possibility, all those ad companies would not have to use tracking cookies :) They could simply check your history.

[How do you access browser history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history) has some shady options, all of which I dont recommend using. This is trying to get privacy sensative user-info. Even after a prompt, users can feel unsecure because they dont know exactly what they are allowing you,

And this probally doesnt work in IE. All moderns browsers are very busy trying to upgrade privacy issues and I dont think they would like this.

---

A method could be writing an browserplugin which can access it maybe, or make your website with a small topbar with a iframe where the users browses, but that is not ideal.

Comment: Not even with a user permission prompt?

Comment: I'll just make a browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Martijn, you cannot visit user's history because it's a security problem.

But I think you can write your own chrome/firefox extensions and publish it to web store.

As I know, `chrome.history` works fine and it is in the chrome developer's document, you can find useage here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only Chrome and Firefox offer full browser history access via an extension.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIBrowserHistory

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done if you have the list of websites they may have visited.  As long as users are aware that their browser history will be used to identify potential interests, I think the `requestAnimationFrame` timing trick is a decent way to parse visited sites.

- **Presentation** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcOQfYlyIqw
- **Whitepaper** https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Stone-Pixel-Perfect-Timing-Attacks-with-HTML5-WP.pdf

You can still use `:visited` but it requires the user to click on links.

- **Profiles based on website generes** http://tinsnail.neocities.org/
- **Browser history as Asteriods game** http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/yahh/